# What is '[0]'in boxcox transformation with scipy.stats.boxcox?

Tags: pandas, scipy

[image: This is a screenshot from a Kaggle's Microcourse]

While performing a boxcox transformation on a series of data, I noticed a certain [0], which I don't quite understand

Answer (score 1):

The `scipy.stats.boxcox` function can return three values (see [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html)). Using `[0]` simply uses indexing to select the first of those three values, i.e. the array that is transformed using the Box-Cox power transformation.

Answer (score 0):

That extracts the first element in the list of outputs.